# How to enable rotation device in only one uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation

I have an app that support only portrait mode, but I have an NowPlayingViewController with youtubeView.
I want only this youtubeView support landscape mode (when it's fullscreen)
I found this (in appdelegate.m)

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([[self.window.subviews.lastObject class].description isEqualToString:@"<string>"]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to set description to my youtubeWiew with this string.
Anyone has solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Rotation has become bit tricky as you can't rotate it forcefully. Though there is a solution, is you need to Customize `UINavigationController` to add Landscape Rotation, and then present the extra view as modal, it will work.

For more clarification see a sample [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78701794/Rotations.zip) I have made for rotations.

I hope it will help you and others.

Cheers.